# magmi column mapper issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

iam using Magmi, iam able to display every product except remote images..

iam thinking i should use column mapper plugin..

so, i have some below doubt related to 'Column Mapper' plugin

**My CSV feedfile column names:**

```
store,websites,type,attribute_set,is_affiliate_product,status,visibility,qty,is_in_stock,tax_class_id,weight,name,meta_keyword,description,sku,manufacturer,price,merchant_buy_link,remote_image_url,main_category,color,for,shoe_type,short_description,remote_thumbnail_image_url,category_ids,merchant_name,merchant_id
```

so, what all columns I need to map and any new columns needs to be added..?

pls kindly suggest me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [documentation for the Image attributes processor](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor).

Your column names for the images are not correct.  The correct column names for images are:

```
image
small_image
thumbnail
```

Comment: I knew my column names are not correct, thats why iam thinking to use  'Column Mapper' plugin with which I can map.. i even tried column mapper plugin, but still not gtetting images into my site....

Comment: You have correct columns listed in the documentation, and you know what columns contain your images.  So why are you asking what columns you need to map?